# Autocoding using RQDA

Tags: r, rqda

I try to use RQDA for quantitative text analysis. I want to code text passages with the same characters automatically.

Let´s say I have the category dog and I marked "dog" in the first sentence and "dogfood" in the fourth. I want RQDA mark "dog" also in the second sentence and "dogfood in the fifth.

[image]

In Maxqda, for example, this is done automatically if I enable the software. Is there a function to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you want to make an automatic coding using RQDA. The function would be `codingBySearch`:

```
codingBySearch(pattern, fid = getFileIds(), cid, seperator,
               concatenate = FALSE)
```

But this function only allows you to make a single pattern per time. If you would like to get a list of patterns, a loop will sort it out:

```
X <- c("pattern1", "pattern2", "pattern3", "pattern4", "pattern5", "pattern6")
for (i in X) {
  codingBySearch(i,fid=getFileIds(),cid=cid_number, seperator="[.!?]",ignore.case=TRUE)
}
```

Where cid is the number of the code you created in the GUID interface. You can also adapt the separators as you see fit.